# app engine cloud sql backup disabled

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud SQL and was successfully able to setup replication and it has been running fine for about a month. But lately, replication has failed and when I check the instance it is saying backups and binary log are disabled. When I try to enable it in the developer console, it doesn't let me enable backups and binary log. The form doesn't give me errors when I change the backup and binary log setting, it just doesn't change them.

The most out-of-the-ordinary change I could think of that might have caused this would be my changing the character set for all tables to be utf8 (they were all in latin1 before). But I didn't get errors from that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that inconvenience.

You unfortunately hit a bug. Fixing is in progress. We will update the thread once the fix is rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update: this is fixed now. Updating the backups shows work both from console.developers.google.com and gcloud tool.